# How can I create the visible horizon from a point?

Tags: qgis, visibility

I'm trying to do shading analysis as part of a building energy simulation and for this I need to find the horizon as seen from the highest part of my building of interest.

I have the MasterMaps Topography layer and building heights saved in a QGIS database. Is there a simple way of creating the horizon from a specific viewpoint from these?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS Plugin for viewshed does exist, you can find description  :

**Plugin: Viewshed Analysis**
Viewshed analysis calculates visible surface from a given observer point over a digital elevation model. This plugin is native to QGIS and intended for more complex modelling, such as the depth below the visible horizon or generation of intervisibilty networks between groups of points. It is particularly performant for multiple viewshed calculations form a set of fixed points. For single point, large area viewsheds the algorithms already available in QGIS (GRASS r.los or SAGA viewshed module) would do the job.

**Reference:**
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/

**Youtube video:**
https://youtu.be/NImNMWSswjA